# How should I style Django validation errors with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

When a form in Django has validation errors, the errors are given in a list with class `errorlist`.

Elements can be given an error style with Bootstrap by setting `class="alert alert-error"`.

What is the best way to combine these, and use Bootstrap's error style for validation errors on Django forms?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Twitter Bootstrap, input elements are enclosed between `"control-group"` `div` or `fieldset`. So I would do something like this in template

```
{%for field in form %}
<div class="control-group {%if field.errors %}error{%endif%}">
{# render your field #}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Note: In bootstrap, `class="alert alert-error"` seems to be for alert messages and not for field specific errors.

Comment: Just a brief comment - with Bootstrap 3, you need "has-error" instead of "error" as the class.

Comment: also with Bootstrap 3 its form-group not control group. See below.

Answer (score 4):

In Bootstrap 3, input elements are enclosed between "form-group" divs and the error class has changed to has-error.

```
{%for field in form %}
  <div class="form-group {%if field.errors %}has-error{%endif%}">
    {# render your field #}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's already been styled! :)

- https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/
- https://github.com/earle/django-bootstrap

These libraries act as a wrapper around your form and adds the relevant class names that is used in Django Bootstrap such that you have a base style (bootstrap default) out of the box

Answer (score 0):

## Bootstrap 4 Django Solution

If `<form class="was-validated>"` returns validation in your response, this will work for you:

This example works for the `admin/change_form.html`, but it is easy to convert it to your form by changing `adminform.form`

**This will not work for Multi widgets like `DateSelectorWidget`**

delete `class="was-validated"`

```html
{% if adminform.form.errors %} {# Delete this if you always want active validations #}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    {% for field in adminform.form %}
      var field_input = document.getElementById("{{ field.auto_id }}");
      if (field_input) {
        field_input.classList.add("is-{% if field.errors %}in{% endif %}valid");
      }
    {% endfor %}
  </script>
{% endif %}
```

**This works for Multi widgets like `DateSelectorWidget` but could introduce problems if one field is called `start` and the other `start_time`**
*Improvements appreciated*

```
{% if adminform.form.errors %} {# Delete this if you always want to see a validation #}
<script type="text/javascript">
  {% for field in adminform.form %}
    var field_input = document.getElementById("{{ field.auto_id }}");
    if (field_input) {
      field_input.classList.add("is-{% if field.errors %}in{% endif %}valid");
    } else {
      multi_widget_fields = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="{{ field.auto_id }}_"]')
      multi_widget_fields.forEach(function (element) {
        element.classList.add("is-{% if field.errors %}in{% endif %}valid");
      });
    }
  {% endfor %}
</script>
{% endif %}
```